# C# OpenFileDialog и SaveFileDialog не открывается

Tags: c#, wpf

```
   private void OpenFileButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog opf = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
        opf.Filter = "bfs file (*.bfs)|*.bfs";
        if (opf.ShowDialog() == WindowForms.DialogResult.OK) {

        }
    }

   private void OpenFileButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog opf = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        opf.Filter = "bfs file (*.bfs)|*.bfs";
        if ((bool)opf.ShowDialog()) {

        }
    }
```

Не могу понять, на Window 7 диалоговое окно выбора фала для загрузки, или аналогичное окно выбора файла для сохранения, открывается нормально. На Windows 2008 R2 при попытке открыть диалоговое окно выбора файла, главное окно моргает фокусом, и диалоговое окно не открывается. В то же время окно выбора папки FolderBrowserDialog открывается нормально.

Comment: может дело в правах приложения, унаследованных от запустившего пользователя?

Comment: Да вообще я запускать программку пробовал именно от имени администратора. И что интересно, ошибок никаких нет, непонятно вообще в чем проблема.

Comment: >> *...диалоговое окно выбора фала для загрузки, или аналогичное окно выбора файла для сохранения...* >> ССЗБ :) вы в своём WPF приложении пытаетесь зачем-то использовать разные диалоги -- в случае "System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog()" это из WinForms.

Comment: Я специально сделал программку с двумя кнопками. На одну кнопку повесил открытие диалогового окна выбора файла через System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog, а на вторую через Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog. Не знаю чем отличаются эти окна из разных пространств имен, но на Windows 7 они оба прекрасно открываются и выглядят они абсолютно одинаково. И на Windows 2008 R2 результат то же одинаковый, т.е. никакой. Хотя такое же диалоговое окно выбора файла прекрасно открывается в том же, скажем, блокноте или Paint-те.

Comment: В принципе мне все равно из какого пространство имен будет диалоговое окно, главное чтобы оно работало.

Comment: т.е. на Win2008R2 **оба варианта** диалога не открываются (в отличие от Win7) ?

Comment: попробуйте задать существующий начальный каталог `.InitialDirectory` до вызова диалога, а то по-умолчанию он пустой.